# null values of @id field not fetched in list hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONFIG")
public class ConfigBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String FEATURE;
    private String SUB_FEATURE;
    private String STATUS;
    private String COMMENTS;
    private String HIERARCHY;
    private String SEARCHCRITERIA;
    private String RULE;
    private String CHECK1;
    private String CHECK2;
    private String CHECK3;
    private String CHECK4;
    private String CHECK5;

    public ConfigBean() {
    }

    public ConfigBean(String FEATURE, String SUB_FEATURE, String STATUS,
        String COMMENTS, String HIERARCHY, String SEARCHCRITERIA,
        String RULE, String CHECK1, String CHECK2, String CHECK3,
        String CHECK4, String CHECK5) {
        this.FEATURE = FEATURE;
        this.SUB_FEATURE = SUB_FEATURE;
        this.STATUS = STATUS;
        this.COMMENTS = COMMENTS;
        this.HIERARCHY = HIERARCHY;
        this.SEARCHCRITERIA = SEARCHCRITERIA;
        this.RULE = RULE;
        this.CHECK1 = CHECK1;
        this.CHECK2 = CHECK2;
        this.CHECK3 = CHECK3;
        this.CHECK4 = CHECK4;
        this.CHECK5 = CHECK5;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "FEATURE" ,  nullable = true)
public String getFEATURE() {
    return FEATURE;
}

public void setFEATURE(String fEATURE) {
    FEATURE = fEATURE;
}

@Column(name = "SUB_FEATURE")
public String getSUB_FEATURE() {
    return SUB_FEATURE;
}

public void setSUB_FEATURE(String sUB_FEATURE) {
    SUB_FEATURE = sUB_FEATURE;
}

@Column(name = "STATUS")
public String getSTATUS() {
    return STATUS;
}

public void setSTATUS(String sTATUS) {
    STATUS = sTATUS;
}

@Column(name = "COMMENTS")
public String getCOMMENTS() {
    return COMMENTS;
}

public void setCOMMENTS(String cOMMENTS) {
    COMMENTS = cOMMENTS;
}

@Column(name = "HIERARCHY")
public String getHIERARCHY() {
    return HIERARCHY;
}

public void setHIERARCHY(String hIERARCHY) {
    HIERARCHY = hIERARCHY;
}

@Column(name = "SEARCHCRITERIA")
public String getSEARCHCRITERIA() {
    return SEARCHCRITERIA;
}

public void setSEARCHCRITERIA(String sEARCHCRITERIA) {
    SEARCHCRITERIA = sEARCHCRITERIA;
}

@Column(name = "RULE")
public String getRULE() {
    return RULE;
}

public void setRULE(String rULE) {
    RULE = rULE;
}

@Column(name = "CHECK1")
public String getCHECK1() {
    return CHECK1;
}

public void setCHECK1(String cHECK1) {
    CHECK1 = cHECK1;
}

@Column(name = "CHECK2")
public String getCHECK2() {
    return CHECK2;
}

public void setCHECK2(String cHECK2) {
    CHECK2 = cHECK2;
}

@Column(name = "CHECK3")
public String getCHECK3() {
    return CHECK3;
}

public void setCHECK3(String cHECK3) {
    CHECK3 = cHECK3;
}

@Column(name = "CHECK4")
public String getCHECK4() {
    return CHECK4;
}

public void setCHECK4(String cHECK4) {
    CHECK4 = cHECK4;
}

@Column(name = "CHECK5")
public String getCHECK5() {
    return CHECK5;
}

public void setCHECK5(String cHECK5) {
    CHECK5 = cHECK5;
}
```

}

Above is my mapping class.
Feature column has many null values in database.

So I am getting 
[image]

I want all the values to be fetched [0..9] and not [0,1,5,9]

below is fetching code

```
public List<ConfigBean> fetchSearchCriteria() throws SQLException {
    criteriaDAO = new ConfigSearchCriteriaDAO();
    // get the checks to perform on the config file.
    List<ConfigBean> searchCriteriaList = criteriaDAO
            .selectRecordsTable("from ConfigBean");
    return searchCriteriaList;
}

public List selectRecordsTable(String queryString) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setMaxResults(10);
    List configList = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return configList;
}
```

The list is fetched from database is ignoring @ID FEATURE values as some of them are null.

Is it necessary that @id column should be not null? 
or is there some other way to get null valued rows included as well ?

Comment: Provide more code: the whole Entity and the way you are trying to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching data from underlying `CONFIG` table here and annotate FEATURE with @Id; i.e. asking hiberanate to fetch only unique records.

You can not distinguish null as a 'unique' value resulting your list only fetching valid unique values.

Just for checking--

1. Try having `FEATURE` column only 2 values repeating at multiple positions ; you will get only 2 distinct values in your list.
2. Try to insert values into `FEATURE` through java, use one of the value as null; you will get unique constraint voilation exception.

Comment: Actually I cannot insert it from java as this was a CSV which i exported to oracle. And I also do not want an auto incr extra column .

Comment: Ok....so if you wanted all values including null to be fetched then remove @id annotation--which I don't think possible as there may be business rules present for this column.